# getting an old logitech webcam to work in Linux

Tags: linux, drivers, camera

I'm trying to get an old Logitech QuickCam Web to work in Linux. There's a [kernel module](http://qce-ga.sourceforge.net/), but the last time it was updated was in 2006 and it doesn't compile against a recent kernel anymore. In particular, it seems to use the old video API V4L1.

There's a [Debian bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=651799) that basically says that the driver has been abandoned. Is anybody aware of a way to make this webcam work with a recent kernel version?

Comment: What is the USB id of the device? Plug it in and run `lsusb`

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice how old this question was. It was on the main page for some reason. I was going to point out that a new driver could very well cover the same USB IDs as the old one...

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. I've abandoned all hope of getting it to work :)

Comment: Darn. I was pretty sure all the IDs were covered by gspca_stv06xx. Did you ever try that one?

Comment: I tried pretty much every driver I could find.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Linux UVC driver and tools](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/) on the Ideas on Board site.

I think in that long list you'll find your model, there are several 2006 era Quickcams.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. The QuickCam Web is also not in the list.